# How reset all Interactive grid Filter Oracle APEX as Page Load Procedure

Tags: oracle-apex

For the Interactive Grid Oracle APEX, How can I the reset all Filters on the Page when a Page load new.

Comment: Hi, what got you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating dynamic action on page load, and set type of action for "Execute JavaScript Code". In code section paste:

```
apex.region("yourReportRegionName").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("reset-report");
```

or if you use APEX 18.1+ the following code should also work:

```
apex.region("projects_report").call("getActions").invoke('reset-report');
```

For more details you can check out Marko Goricki's github https://github.com/mgoricki/orclapex-ig-cheat-sheet . There are planty usefull tricks there, and also links to John Synder's blog.

Comment: It does not work, does not delete the Filler Dialog :o(